# how to copy url without "www" to the url with "www"?

Tags: django, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm hosting a Django project, let's say the name is `www.example.com`, when an user search for `example.com/subname` to redirect to `www.example.com/subname`. Unfortunalety, right now it's redirecting to `www.example.com` without adding the "subname" part to my url.

I have my domain name on infomaniak which redirects `example.com` to `www.example.com`, the hosting is on pythonanywhere where it handles my Django project.

How can I achieve the case where what's put after domain name url is kept and used to redirect to the one with `www.` ?

(For my Django project I'm not using apache nor nginx, so where is the htaccess file if the changes has to be made there ?)

---

UPDATE for Udlei Nati's answer :

[image]

---

UPDATE 2 : for  Astik Anand : This is where the actual redirection is made. (`site.com` redirect to another site which was the old version of the one on `www.` (that's why I'm trying to override it.))

[image]

Comment: What does your code or htaccess file look like?

Comment: To add to what Evan Carslake said, the first thing you’ll want to do is find out why it is currently redirecting from domain.com to www.domain.com. This isn’t automatic—many sites have completely separate sites on domain.com than they do on www.domain.com and don’t do a redirect. Once you find out where the redirect is happening, you’ll probably also have figured out how to make it do what you want.

Comment: @JerryStratton I set up my DNS on pythonanywhere on `www.mysite.com`, the thing is that `mysite.com` is not redirected to the same DNS, it's connected to the old site which was made with Drupal 7 (so yes it's a complete separated site on another plateform). The redirect is happening on Infomaniak which is host my domain name and the old site. But since Django Framework (for the new website) is not supported on their hosting service we host in somewhere else usign redirect from `mysite.com` to `www.mysite.com`.

Comment: which web server you are using?

Comment: @AstikAnand I think Pythonanywhere (the hosting service) handle the servers, but I use Gunicorn.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lindow

Comment: And one more thing have you checked why it is redirecting from non-www to www because it doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: @AstikAnand Yes of course, see post 2nd update, I'm showing how I'm redirecting, unfortunately the hosting provider don't let me configure `site.ch/something` to `www.site.ch/something`.

Comment: Thanks for clearance @Lindow